Extract categories from large block of ,Heading separated, text
I have a large block of text as such:
123LoremABC

==Heading 1==
    123456789...

==Heading 2==
    abcdefg....
    
    ===Sub-Heading 1===
        lorem...

    ===Sub-Heading 2===
        abc123...

...


Every heading follows the pattern of ==(Heading)== with sub-headings gaining an extra = for each layer down it goes. However the number of headings and sub-headings(or even the existence) is not guaranteed
How would i go about converting this to a structure similar to this:
{
"Text/Header": "123LoremABC",
"Heading 1": {
       "Text": "123456789..."
             },
"Heading 2": {
       "Text": "abcdefg...",
       "Sub-Heading 1": {
               "Text": "lorem..."
                        },
       "Sub-Heading 2": {
                "Text": "abc123...",
                "SubSub-Heading1": {
                             "Text": "Example"
                                   }                                      
                         }
             },
}


I have already tired splitting the text on concurrent appearances of ==* but this was messy and forced me to reconstruct every category. As well as any instances of = in the text would ruin it.
Im also not well enough informed about regex to create a solution incorporating this myself.

You might have success using PyParsing to define the grammar of what you consider to be section headings etc
